# Unit Tests - method of user controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, controller

I have a Controller named "UserController" with method named "Invite". My controller has the following override method:

```
DBRepository _repository;
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
    base.Initialize(requestContext);
            _repository = new DBRepository();

}
```

so, this method is called each time when UserController class is created.

My method "Invite" has the following lines:

```
var startTime = _repository.Get<AllowedTime>(p => p.TimeID == selectTimeStart.Value);
```

but when I try to call this method via Unit method:

```
[TestMethod()]
[UrlToTest("http://localhost:6001/")]
public void InviteTest()
{
    UserController target = new UserController(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
    int? selectTimeStart = 57;
    int? selectTimeEnd = 61;
    Nullable<int> selectAttachToMeeting = new Nullable<int>(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
    int InvitedUserID = 9; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
    UserInviteModel model = new UserInviteModel();
    model.Comment = "BLA_BLA_BLA";
    ActionResult expected = null; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
    ActionResult actual;
    actual = target.Invite(selectTimeStart, selectTimeEnd, selectAttachToMeeting, InvitedUserID, model);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.");
}
```

I got an error "Reference is not set...". I understand why it happens (_repository is null because Initialize method is not called in my case, but how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect DBRepository to actually perform the `Get` from your backing data store during your test, you could change your `_repository` field to be a `Lazy<DBRepository>`, that gets initialized upon first use. (I'm assuming it's being `new`ed up in the Initialize method rather than the constructor because it relies on the current request context?)

If you want this to be a true unit test, it shouldn't test the DBRepository class at all: you should be programming to an interface that you can mock up. Additionally, you need to make it so that your `DBRepository` comes from someplace where it can be provided by the test case. You could have it built by a factory or provided as a singleton, and the test case could set up the factory or singleton to provide a mocked object ahead of time. However, the *best* approach would be to use Dependency Injection, so you can provide a fake/mock IDBRepository when you construct the `new UserController()`.

Comment: @user285336: Unfortunately, this is a pretty vast topic, and the specific implementation in your case would depend somewhat on details about your system that are beyond the scope of a StackOverflow question. The best thing I can suggest is to spend some time researching Dependency Injection and Mocking in relation to Unit Tests.